# Using Orderby with conditional?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Hello I am trying to get a query to order by dates but if there is a due_date to use that if there isn't a due_date it needs to use sample_date. This is what i tried but it isnt correct.

[image]

is there a way to use a conditional in a orderby or a thenby or no?

expecting:
[image]

what i got:
[image]

Comment: Does `ThenBy(x => x.due_date ?? x.sample_date)` work? Not sure how nhibernate will translate that.

Comment: Try something like `.ThenBy(x => x.due_date ?? x.sample_date)` or `.ThenBy(x => x.due_date != null ? x.due_date  : x.sample_date)`

Comment: Yes the ThenBy(x=> x.due_date ?? x.sample_date) worked thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nulls appear in ascending sorting as first records. We can avoid this by coalesce operator:

```cs
session.Query<ActiveTestListResult>()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.lab_int)
    .ThenBy(x => x.due_date ?? x.sample_date)
    .ThenBy(x => x.sample_id)
    .ThenBy(x => x.batch_id)
```

Comment: And will this work with nhibernate?

Comment: @DavidG, why not? It is not too stupid. It uses `Relinq` for query translation.

Comment: Should not it be `.ThenBy(x => x.due_date ?? x.sample_date)`?

Comment: Yes, it might work, I just don't know without testing. That is why I didn't supply an answer before OP confirmed.

Comment: @GuruStron, yes, typo. Original question is image.

Comment: This works thanks but its OrderByDescending not OrderDescending.